# Why is VS 2019 not loading MSBuild.Sdk.Extras project sdk type?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, caliburn.micro

i cloned the Caliburn.Micro repository to my local machine and when i try to open the projects Visual Studio doesn't load them and it displays this output

```
error  : The expression "[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName('')" cannot be evaluated. The path is not of a legal form.  C:\Users\MyUserName\.nuget\packages\msbuild.sdk.extras\2.0.54\Sdk\Sdk.props
```

What could be the issue ?

Note that i don't have all target platform SDKs installed, i only need .net framework and .net standard

[image: VS Output and .csprog file screenshot]

Comment: I don't think that you can use SDK style projects without .NET Core SDK installed

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski i do have .net core 3.1 sdk  installed as well, just not mono or xamarin .

Comment: do you have any special characters in username?

Comment: https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/688

Comment: @magicandre1981 nope no special chars, simple name of five lower case letters

Comment: @HansPassant that was the issue exactly, i was able to open the projects.
i had to install .net sdk version 3.1.101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is VS 2019 not loading MSBuild.Sdk.Extras project sdk type?

**First**, thanks to **Hans Passant** for kindess guidance.

To help other community members handle this issue, I have added an answer and add more

detailed info:

Since [Caliburn.Micro](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro) is **Net Core Sdk** project and to build this type of project, you should install the related Net Core SDK version. And from the `global.json` file indicates,  it needs at least [Net Core 3.1.101](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core).

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.101"
  },
  "msbuild-sdks": {
    "MSBuild.Sdk.Extras": "2.0.54"
  }
}
```

Higher **Net Core SDK** version is compatible with lower versions.

**Solution**

So please install **>=**`Net Core 3.1.101` version and then you will not face the issue again.

**Update 1**

You would better install [Net Core 3.1.101 sdk](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1) and higher versions of the **Net Core SDK** may fail to compile this project for some reasonS.

Comment: Actually i have a higher .Net Core Sdk version already installed, but for some reason visual studio wasn't able to load the projects until i installed the specific version mentioned in global.json